# Generated apk crashes out

Tags: android

I've just finished my last android project but I'm facing a weird problem. All the time I was working on the app, I used to run it on my device by clicking that green button and it worked fine. But now that I've created my app's apk file, it installes on device with no problem, but at the time I want to start the app, it crashes out and never starts.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE: Dependencies:**

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v14:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.codekidX:storage-chooser:2.0.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

**ViewModel Class:**

```
private class MyImageViewModel: ViewModel(){
    fun returnImagePath(): String{
        return createdImageFile
        //createdImageFile is a global string that contains the path of an image and its default value is ""
    }
}
```

**ViewModelUsage:**

```
val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyImageViewModel::class.java)
    createdImageFile = model.returnImagePath()
    if (createdImageFile != ""){
        //do sth with the image file path
    }
```

Comment: Did you select v1 and v2 while making the release apk?

Comment: @UmangBurman I selected both

Comment: Connect phone to laptop and open android studio, then launch the app installed on phone and check what logcat has to say and post here.

Comment: @UmangBurman I'm using ViewModel in my app. logcat says Cannot create an instance of the ViewModel class

Comment: ViewModel from Android Architecture?

Comment: @UmangBurman Yes

Comment: Can you post your dependencies please. Edit your question and paste it. Also paste the activity class in which app crashes..

Comment: @UmangBurman The post has been updated.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your comment but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @UmangBurman My question is if sth is wrong with view model, why does it work when the app is started by android studio?

Comment: I'm posting a solution. try that. and update me. okay. This is in kotlin, but I did it in java in my iMac

Comment: @Soroush Just curious do you have Proguard enabled? Maybe it is stripping out something in release builds that is needed to create ViewModel.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I have but I disabled it and tried again. Nothing changed

Comment: just a min, i'll try myself in kotlin and see what is the problem..

Comment: @UmangBurman Thanks for the time you spent dude. Look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help, I found the problem. It is a little stupid thing. ViewModel class should not be private! That's it.

Comment: Great... How did it work in my device? can you answer that dude?

Comment: Well, Congrats that it worked, but I don't think that initialization depends on private or public. Anyway happy coding.

Comment: @UmangBurman No I have seen this in other topics too. like https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969087/10245431

Comment: Oh, Okay, may be I implemented public class then in my app.. I did not notice i guess.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Instead of:

```
val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyImageViewModel::class.java)
```

write:

```
var model: MyImageViewModel()
```

then,

```
model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyImageViewModel::class.java)
```

Try it, Hopefully it should work.

Comment: Sorry nothing changed

Comment: @Soroush Sorry, but I had no such errors.. Infact I used your code, your dependency, everything. App works fine. My device Moto X Play. I made the apk, copied in internal storage, installed opened fine.

Comment: @Soroush Try this: "'implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1' -ktx
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1' -ktx"